# React 16 counter value inside setState methods gets propagated in next list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have achieved to increase the list items count values and cost assigned to them using `reduce`, `setState` methods e.g `Tea x 2` (clicked n times, here 2) then cost will become `15 x 2 = 30`; depends on the number of clicks. This is working.

When I click on first items e.g `Tea x 1 = 15` then the second item twice coffee x 2.
What actually happens is the `counter` and `cost` gets added to coffee item and both items display `counter` as `Tea x 2` also `coffee x 2`.
Where expected is `Tea x 1` and `coffee x 2` as clicked twice. So here `setState` or `counter` do not handle with multiple click values.

What am I missing here?

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

const MorningDrinks = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Tea",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Coffee",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Milk",
    cost: 15
  }
];

const ChoclateDrinks = [
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Smothe",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "hot Chocolate",
    cost: 15
  }
];

class MenuCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: [],
    counter: 1
  };

  selectItem = item => {
    if (this.state.selectedItems.includes(item)) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedItems: prevState.selectedItems,
        counter: ++this.state.counter
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedItems: prevState.selectedItems.concat(item)
      }));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <p>
          Welcome {this.props.name} !Pick your any Break-fast menu you want{" "}
        </p>
        <Row>
          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h2>Morning Drinks </h2>

              {MorningDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  {item.name} {item.cost}{" "}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <h2>Chocolate Drinks </h2>
              {ChoclateDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >
                  {item.name}
                  {item.cost}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>

          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h2>Your orders </h2>
              {this.state.selectedItems.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  {item.name}
                  {item.cost}
                  {this.state.counter}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>

          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h3>Total</h3>

              {this.state.selectedItems.reduce(
                (acc, item) => acc + item.cost * this.state.counter,
                0
              )}
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuCard;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining your implementation I made few changes to your existing code. See below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

const MorningDrinks = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Tea",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Coffee",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Milk",
    cost: 15
  }
];

const ChoclateDrinks = [
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Smoothie",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Hot Chocolate",
    cost: 15
  }
];

class MenuCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: []
  };

  selectItem = item => {
    const { counter, selectedItems } = this.state;
    const newItem = {
      ...item,
      quantity: 1
    };

    // check if item already exist
    const el = selectedItems.filter(el => el.id === newItem.id);

    if (selectedItems.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        selectedItems: [...selectedItems, newItem]
      });
    } else {

      if (el.length) {
        const newSelectedItems = selectedItems.map((item) => {
          if (item.id === newItem.id) {
            item.quantity++;
          }

          return item;
        });

        this.setState({
          selectedItems: newSelectedItems
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          selectedItems: [...selectedItems, newItem]
      });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { counter, selectedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <p>
          Welcome {this.props.name}! Pick your any Break-fast menu you want{" "}
        </p>
        <Row>
          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h2>Morning Drinks </h2>

              {MorningDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >
                  {" "}
                  {item.name} {item.cost}{" "}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <h2>Chocolate Drinks </h2>
              {ChoclateDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >
                  {item.name} {item.cost}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>

          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h2>Your orders </h2>
              {selectedItems.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  {item.name} {item.cost} {item.quantity}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>

          <Col xs="3">
            <ul>
              <h3>Total</h3>

              {selectedItems.reduce(
                (acc, item) => acc + item.cost * item.quantity,
                0
              )}
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuCard;
```

[image: Edit 938ow6px9p]

Answer (score 1):

Under your current implementation: `counter` is a blanket `variable` that `increments` once per click ***anywhere*** in your `menu`.

Hence, `counter` only knows *`total` `clicks`*, not *`individual` `clicks`*.

I assume you want to `count` `clicks` per `item`.

The easiest way to do this would be within your record of each `item` that has been clicked.

Your problem is a lot easier to solve if you manage your `cart` (`selectedItems`) in `object` form, wherein each object carries an individual `quantity` property.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Drinks.
const drinks = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "tea",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "coffee",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "milk",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "smoothie",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "hot chocolate",
    cost: 15
  }
]

// Menu.
class Menu extends React.Component {

  // Constructor.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) // Super Props.
    this.state = {cart: {}} // Initial State.
  }

  // Render.
  render() {

    // Variables.
    const { state } = this // State.
    const { cart } = state // Drinks.

    return (
      <div>

        {/* Drinks. */}
        <ul>
          <h2>Drinks</h2>
          {drinks.map((drink, index) => (
            <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} key={drink.id} onClick={() => this.addToCart(drink)}>
              {drink.name} ${(drink.cost).toFixed(2)}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>

        {/* Cart. */}
        <ul>
          <h2>Cart</h2>
          {Object.keys(cart).map((key, index) => (
            <li key={key}>
              ${(cart[key].cost).toFixed(2)}
              {cart[key].name}
              {cart[key].quantity}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>


        {/* Total. */}
        <ul>
          <h3>Total</h3>
          ${Object.keys(cart).reduce((total, key) => total + (cart[key].cost * cart[key].quantity), 0).toFixed(2)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

  // Add To Cart.
  addToCart = (item) => {

    // Variables.
    const { state } = this // State.
    const { cart } = state // Selected Items.
    const { id } = item

    // Is In Cart?
    const isInCart = cart[id] // Is In Cart.
    if (isInCart)  return this.setState({cart: {...cart, [id]: {...cart[id], quantity: cart[id].quantity + 1}}}) // Update Cart.
    
    // Does Not Exist.
    return this.setState({cart: {...cart, [id]: {...item, quantity: 1}}}) // Add To Cart.
  }
}



// ReactDOM.render.
ReactDOM.render(<Menu/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sure bro; all the best.